# IPad App With UIWebView Or Custom View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiwebview, tableview

This is not a cry to help correct the code. I have a simple app that is parsing an rss feed and displaying data (images, title, publisher etc.) in the UITableview. The user taps on any entry in the tableview and it segues to the UIWebView.

For iPhone, the UIWebView shows the mobile website and i have done some minor customisations to the mobile site so it looks much better in the UIWebView inside my app.

But for iPad, it does not show the mobile site and instead displays the normal website that makes it look bad with its own controls like navigation etc. allowing users to browse it website functions instead the ones i am offering with the app.

My question is can i just submit this app to the App Store? Are there any chances my app can get rejected due to this behaviour?

Kindly also suggest if there is any alternative solution using UIWebView without making a custom view controller for this purpose.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Forcing the mobile site to display for iPad users is not the right thing to do. Just read a document from Apple that says ""If you have a version of your website that is optimized for mobile devices with small screens, do NOT serve this mobile version to iPad users." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple could very well reject an app for not looking very good, it's really their choice, and it depends on who reviews the app.

I'd probably try to find a solution outside of iOS, you can always force the site to load the mobile version for iPads (not that some people like this).

If you use Apache, you can always use something similar to the following in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

#if request_uri is _not_ followed by mobile
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$

#if the user agent is ipad
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPad.*$

#Redirect to /mobile/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried the solution you answered but it breaks the whole mobile theme when presented inside the uiwebview for iPad.

Comment: There's probably some css/js that needs to be re-directed.  You can do so like this, put the line above the first RewriteCond rule:  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js)$`  Also, not sure if you can do this, but I'd change the flags on the post to include apache and htaccess, you'd likely get some more qualified person to help provide a more complete solution.

Comment: No it didn't work. Also i think forcing the mobile site to display on iPad is not the right thing to do. Just read a document by Apple that says "If you have a version of your website that is optimized for mobile devices with small screens, do NOT serve this mobile version to iPad users." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/

Answer (score 0):

If your mobile version does not fit well inside the iPad, just make a new version or fix the issues in the original site, sending the site to App Store embedded in a webview would only make your work harder when you need a real fast update.

Comment: The tableview pushes the link to the webview which has refresh, stop, move forward and back and share to social networks features. what i am asking for is how the content is displayed inside the webview for iPad

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)'s `–webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method, and modifing the User-Agent (and/or any other headers) to bring up the mobile site, instead of the desktop version.

Comment: I haven't used this delegate method but if it handles only the links, refreshing, go back and forward, i have already implemented these functionalities in the Webview. What i am interested in is how the WebView content is displayed.

Comment: Also i have already updated the question with an Apple document that suggests that we should not force the mobile site for IPad device.

Comment: The delegate method allows you to intercept any request made by a UIWebView and modify it as you want. And, well, yes, its bad to force people to a mobile site. But, you *can* if you wanted to.